# Store flash 'check box' data to a local text file

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

Could somebody help me or tell me if this is even possible. I want to make a simple tick box questionaire in Flash (AS2) that  stores data to a local text file when the user has submitted the form. So simple stuff like are you Male of Female etc... 
Is it possible for flash to store this information somewhere. It is for touch screens in an exhibition space so it wont be online. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Now try yourself before you ask here

Answer (score 0):

First store your select button into a variable, than convert your answer toString()

```
var myVariable = whatever.toString();

function Writefile(event:MouseEvent) {
var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
bytes.writeUTFBytes(myVariable);
file.save(bytes,"test.txt");//can be whatever.txt,php,hello just open in txtEditor
}

SaveBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,Writefile );
```

Add either a button to stage or an updateEvent, this should help you